# Цикл с несколькими разными значениями

Tags: python, for

Как можно запустить цикл с разным количеством данных в нем?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]

for i,j in zip(a,b):
    print(i,j)
```

то выводит меньшую часть. Как можно сделать так, чтобы выводились оба, даже если у одного больше, чем у другого?

Comment: А что по вашему представлению должно выводиться при значении  i=4 ?

Comment: Зуфар, старайтесь, пожалуйста, писать яснее. Я понимаю, что русский не родной, но я совсем не смог понять, что вы хотите. И в коде пропустили `:` (я исправил)

Comment: `from itertools import zip_longest`

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_lists(list1, list2):
    if list1 > list2:
        ret_arr = []
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            try:
                ret_arr.append((list1[i], list2[i]))
            except:
                ret_arr.append((list1[i], None))
        return ret_arr
    elif list1 < list2:
        ret_arr = []
        for i in range(len(list2)):
            try:
                ret_arr.append((list1[i], list2[i]))
            except:
                ret_arr.append((None, list2[i]))
        return ret_arr
    elif list1 == list2:
        return list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Результат работы  с массивом **a** и **b**:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, None)]
```

Теперь выведем в виде указанном в вопросе:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]
mergeList = merge_lists(a, b)

for i in mergeList:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Вывод:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 None
```